# Can I put a Joomla extension as the only item at frontend?

Tags: joomla

What I need to do is to put a Joomla extension, JDownloads, as the only item at the frontend. I mean, no menus, no header, no footer, no other things at frontend, only JDownloads.

I'm a newbie in Joomla, so I have to ask. Is this possible, at first place? If it is, how can achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: menu, footer etc are all module so simply disable the modules for those pages ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do anything other than make a single menu item to your JDownloads component. If you don't add any modules then all that will display is the component.

Comment: It did the job! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You could fork one of your templates (atomic is the simplest one) eg from

> /templates/atomic

to

> /templates/simply

tweak a few parameters in /templates/simply/templateDetails.xml

```
<name>atomic</name>
```

and in /templates/simply/index.php replace the contents of BODY tag with:

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Then set it as your default template or use as **helper** for other site

Comment: forking a template and messing around with the `index.php` is a little too far. Brent's answer is far more simple. Only thing that needs doing is disabling modules for that specific page.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot agree. Simplified template means far less processing. That's it